# How to rebase a patch having dependent commits by updating those dependent commits to latest in git

Tags: git, git-rebase

So, i am on the branch bug/156453 and my git log shows my patch on the top followed by few commits from other teammate. Now, I want to rebase my own patch because team mate has updated the patches (dependent patches for my patch) and so what I am looking is rebase with latest version of my team mate's patches. Is there a smaller way than cherry picking his patches, downloading my patch and then run git review. 
Inputs will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do if you have a "messy" situation like is to create a new temporary branch (name = "temp") from your current/latest state. Then rebase everything else from the actual working branch into "temp".

When you're done, you can delete the original branch and rename "temp" to the original name. Don't forget to add the remote again.

This solution might be a bit "hacky" but saved me in a lot of situations when I messed up my own repo.

Comment: Ah good to know, I kinda got my answer, I will run "git review -d <latest_dependent_commit>" and then cherry pick my patch on top of it and push it. :) Thanks for your input though.